# Eclipselink NamedNativeQuery pass column name as parameter and not a value

Tags: eclipselink, jpa-2.1

Trying to pass column name as parameter but JPA sets it as a value surrounding it with single quotes.

```
@NamedNativeQueries({
    @NamedNativeQuery(
            name = "Genre.findAllLocalized",
            query = "SELECT "
                    + " CASE "
                    + "     WHEN ? IS NULL THEN genre_default"
                    + "     ELSE ? "
                    + " END localized_genre "
                    + "FROM genre ORDER BY localized_genre")
})
```

Then:

```
List<String> res = em.createNamedQuery("Genre.findAllLocalized")
                .setParameter(1, colName)
                .setParameter(2, colName)
                .getResultList();
```

The problem is that the column names being passed are taken as **values** so the result will return result list with repeated values of `"col_name"` instead of selecting the value of the column passed as parameter.

Is this achievable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically it makes no sense to create a prepared query like this, how would you name that query anyway: "*"? So the short answer is: no.

1. But you could create named queries dynamically if this matches your requirement:

   ```
   String colName = "colName";
   String query = "SELECT WHEN " + colName + " IS NULL THEN genre_default";
   Query query = entitymanager.createQuery(query);
   ```
2. Probably using a criteria builder is more the way you want to use JPA (code from https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Java_Persistence/Criteria):

   ```
   // Select the employees and the mailing addresses that have the same address.
   CriteriaBuilder criteriaBuilder = entityManager.getCriteriaBuilder();
   CriteriaQuery criteriaQuery = criteriaBuilder.createQuery();
   Root employee = criteriaQuery.from(Employee.class);
   Root address = criteriaQuery.from(MailingAddress.class);
   criteriaQuery.multiselect(employee, address);

   criteriaQuery.where( criteriaBuilder.equal(employee.get("address"), address.get("address"));
   Query query = entityManager.createQuery(criteriaQuery);
   List<Object[]> result = query.getResultList();
   ```

Comment: that is a bad idea since you open the possibility of SQL Injection

Comment: @H4F: 1. If you are giving a user the option to create queries your architecture is in most cases more than questionable. 2. With the second way injection is completely impossible at all.